# I want add the data row wise in power bi

Tags: sql, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

[image]

I have done cohort analysis in Power bi using matrix visual and I just want to add data in year wise for example In columns is showing month year So, Year1 is (Feb-2020 to Jan-2021)
Let Suppose,

In rows Is Month Year Like Jan-2020,Feb-2020 Etc. If Jan-2020 in rows then Add the data from Feb-2020 to Jan-2021 column wise and
In rows Is Month Year Like Feb-2020,Mar-2020 Etc. If Feb-2020 in rows then Add the data from Mar-2020 to Feb-2021 column wise.

Kindly help to get out from this problem.

[image]

I am expecting this output

Comment: You will need to share what your data table looks, together with any other relevant tables (like a Date table). Update your question with this and ensure you paste headers with sample data in the correct [markdown format](https://tabletomarkdown.com/).

Comment: I had calculated Customer retention 
So i have Date column and UniqueID in main table. 
I have created 2 tables is Date Table and First Date table
Date Table Relation with Date column and First Date table relation with First order date Column in main sheet and Created one measure for calculate unique customers. Only i want to add rows wise data .
Anything else you want to please let me know

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, but it is hard to follow and visualize. Please  [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77576542/edit) your question above, with the relevant tables and sample rows - or share a PBIX.